# Celery task is delayed when another task runs, how do I make sure multi-threading here?

Tags: django, celery, gevent

We have a celery worker and a beat scheduler running in production, in a dedicated Kubernetes POD.
We used gevent and run celery with concurrency set to 200.

`celery -A app worker -l info --pool=gevent --concurrency=200`

Recently, we needed to have a periodic task to be triggered every 5 seconds.
But when there is another celery task in progress (especially the ones that interact with the database), we noticed the task is delayed a lot. Checking the beat-scheduler, the tasks are sent every 5 seconds without problems but they are waiting in the broker.
We hoped this periodic task was not affected by other tasks because we used concurrency.

Please see [screenshot of logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxdza.png)

We need to make sure this task runs every 5 seconds regardless of other tasks.